# Replacing the nth word with regex

Tags: regex

I have a csv file where I need to change the 7th and the 8th "cell" with a value from a list.  I'm trying to do a replace with a regex but I'm having trouble defining the regex.

I tried `(\"\w+\").*?(\"\w+\"){7}` but without the number the regex appends the 2 cells.

`(?:[^\"]\w+\")` just leaves the first " behind.

And `(\"\w+\")?(\"\w+\")` matches every cell.

What I need is given the following line:

> "b34";"es";"ee";"beer";"beers";"34421";"bye";"bi";"buuu";"fffs"

Get the 7th word that would be `"bye"`

Please help, thanks

Comment: A weird [`^("[^"]*"(?:;"[^"]*"){5};)"[^"]*";"[^"]*"`](https://regex101.com/r/uC7gU7/2) may help, perhaps.

Comment: So do you just want bye or do you want bye and bi?

Comment: What language are you using (e.g. perl, python, C, javascript)?  It can make a difference.  Are you required to use _just_ a regex?  This might be more easily handled with a `split` (available in perl/python) and the C equiv is `strtok` along with `index` (`strchr` in C) in addition to a regex.  I do regexes _every_ day, so add some more info and I'll be glad to post an answer.  You mentioned replacement, you posted the input, so please post the expected output for this.

Comment: Hi, here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1qzozu07/5/ What I'm expecting is to change only "bye" the 7th position, no matter if there are exactly the same values in all other cells

Comment: You can simply split the whole string by semicolon **;** and then access the 7'th cell.

Comment: Yes That was what I was thinking... but I want to learn how to do it with regex

Comment: Got you, I'll make some regex for you and explain in details. just a minute
But - it's important to note that in different platforms, regex interpreted differently.

Comment: You used my example, but did not use the `$1` back-reference. See [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1qzozu07/6/).

Comment: Yes that one works thanks! add it as an answer please ;)

Comment: @AnaFranco: I added an answer, please let me know if you need more explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regexps do not work because:

- `(\"\w+\").*?(\"\w+\"){7}` - matches `"`, 1 or more alphanumerics, `"`, and then 0 or more (but as few as possible) any characters other than a newline, then 7 occurrences of a quoted alphanumeric string. It is clear you will get past the 7th value with this regex (since you already required to match 8).
- `(?:[^\"]\w+\")` - Matches 1 character that is not `"` (with `[^"]`), then 1 or more alphanumerics (with `\w+`) and then a `"`. It is clear this one will only match 1 field with no spaces.
- `(\"\w+\")?(\"\w+\")` - this matches 1 or 0 quoted alphanumeric subtstring, and then 1 quoted alphanumeric susbtring. Again, this will not get you to the 7th field.

Note that you do not need `/i` modifier since you are not using any letters in the pattern. The case-insensitive modifier is necessary when you need to make your regex pattern case-insensitive (i.e. match `E` and `e` with `e` or `E`).

You can use

```
/^("[^"]*"(?:;"[^"]*"){5};)"[^"]*"/
```

Or, contracting it a bit further (since `;` is always expected on the right):

```
/^((?:"[^"]*";){6})"[^"]*"/
```

The regex matches

- `^` - start of string
- `((?:"[^"]*";){6})` - (capture group 1) - *exactly 6 occurrences* (due to the limiting quantifier `{6}`) of a `"..."`-like quoted substring followed by a `;`
- `"[^"]*"` - a quoted substring that does not have a `"` inside it (the 7th field value).

Here is a working JS snippet:

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
        var line = '"b34";"es";"ee";"beer";"beers";"34421";"bye";"bi";"buuu";"fffs"';

    var regex = /^((?:"[^"]*";){6})"[^"]*"/;

    var result = line.replace(regex, '$1"hello"');                                             
    $("#result").val(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="palabra">"b34";"es";"ee";"beer";"beers";"34421";"bye";"bi";"buuu";"fffs"</div><br/>

<div>
<input type="text" id="result" value="" style="width:400px;"/>
</div><br/>

<div id="palabra">Expected: "b34";"es";"ee";"beer";"beers";"34421";"hello";"bi";"buuu";"fffs"</div><br/>
<button id="button" >Run regex</button>
```

Comment: Nice solution, and very well explained. Don't see any reason to upload my answer now.

Comment: You can simplify the regex to `^((?:"[^"]*";){6})"[^"]*";"[^"]*"`

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
^((?:".*?";){6})"(.*?)";"(.*)$
```

First capture is the first six fields, next is field seven, and the third capture is everything else afterwards.

https://regex101.com/r/hV2oS7/2

Comment: Thanks but this one leaves the end behind in my replace

Comment: The start is `$1`, you want to replace `$2` and then tack on `$3` to the end. If you mention what tool you're using I can clarify. sed?

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of your data to simplify the regex:

```
/([^;]+;){6}"([^"]+)"/
```

Now `$2` has *bye*

Comment: This fails if `;` occurs within quotes.

Comment: @JeffY Remember when I said "take advantage of your data"?  You _can't_ have a ; inside the string because of the format of a CSV, as ; is the field delimiter here.  And, OP [in comments] was considering split which also implies this.  If ; were allowed inside the string, OP should have posted that as example data for such an edge case.

Comment: Depending on the format of CSV, the field can contain `;`, as long as it's quoted.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I made a change to your regex and replace function.

```
var regex = /^((?:"[^"]*";){6})"[^"]*"/i;

var result = line.replace(regex, '$1' + replacement);
```

The `$1` matches the first capture group which is everything in the first six cells.

Try it out here:

https://jsfiddle.net/L19ru04s/

This is the pattern:

```
^((?:"[^"]*";){6})"[^"]*"
```

https://regex101.com/r/lR5xU5/1

It looks for six occurrences of `"TEXT";`, and puts them in a capture group, then captures the next cell after that *outside* of the capture group.  That way, when we are replacing the first seven cells, we can use the capture group for the first six cells to keep them around.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to capture the `"..."` that occurs with 6 non-captured instances of `"...";` before it:

```
(?:"[^"]*";){6}("[^"]*")
```

To capture the 8th alone, change the 6 to 7, or to capture both 7th and 8th:

```
(?:"[^"]*";){6}("[^"]*");("[^"]*")
```

https://regex101.com/r/hL0vD9/1

Comment: Thanks but this one leaves the start behind in my replace

Comment: I see, you want it the other way: capture only the first part: `(("[^"]*";){6})"[^"]*"`.  Then substitute `$1"new"` for the whole expression.